# HLF v1.0.2 Structure of the transaction log (a.k.a chain)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

As the third party auditor I'd like to veryfy the blocks' hashes in the chain. I'd like to write my own tool which audit physical chain files located at:

```
/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains/<channel_name>/blockfile_*
```

on each peer.

Q: What is the structure of the chain files?

I've read the documentation and I cannot find any information regarding structure of the blockchain physical files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package that manages these files is the [common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage) package. In particular,  blkstorage_serialization.go has the methods that store and access the data in the blocks.

```
type serializedBlockInfo struct {
    blockHeader *common.BlockHeader
    txOffsets   []*txindexInfo
    metadata    *common.BlockMetadata
}

//The order of the transactions must be maintained for history
type txindexInfo struct {
    txID string
    loc  *locPointer
}
```

You might develop something derived from this package.